# Separating a C program into void functions

Tags: c, void

I am new to programming.  I am trying to split this program into smaller pieces.  Firstly, the piece I am looking at is item 3.2: InitializeAccumulators. The program is running, however the math keeps creating super long numbers.  Secondly, I am looking at piece 3.7: AddDetailToAccumulators. This program won't run. It has an issue with the payrate variable. Any thoughts?  Thanks a million!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "TAXRATES.h"
#include "EmployeeRecord.h"
#include "CalcTaxes.o"
#define ADDR(var) &var
#define REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS1 "Employee           Pay    Reg Hrs  Gross    Fed     SSI     Net\n"
#define REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS2 "Name               Rate   OVT Hrs  Pay      State   Defr    Pay\n"
#define BARS                  "========           =====  =======  =======  ======  ======  =======\n\n"  
#define REPORTCOLUMN1         "%s, %s\t%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n"
#define REPORTCOLUMN2         "%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n\n"

void PrintReportHeadings(FILE *ReportFile);//3.1
void InitializeAccumulators(float *totpr,float *totreg,float *totovt,float *totgp,float *totfed,
                        float *totstt,float *totsst,float *totdef,float *totnp,int *empCount);//3.2
extern void CalculateTaxes(float gross, float defr, float *ft, float *st, float *ssit);//3.5
void AddDetailToAccumulators(int *empCount,float *totpr,float *totfed,float *totreg,float *totovt,
                         float *totgp,float *totstt,float *totsst,float *totnp,float *totdef,float *r.payrate);//3.7


int main()
{
    EmployeeRecord r;

    float reghours,ovthours; 
    float ft,st,ssit;
    float totpr,totreg,totovt,totgp,totfed,totstt,totsst,totdef,totnp;
    float avgpr,avgreg,avgovt,avggp,avgfedt,avgstt,avgsst,avgdef,avgnp;
    char answer;
    int empCount;
    FILE *ReportFile;

    void PrintReportHeadings(FILE *ReportFile);//3.1            
    void InitializeAccumulators(float *totpr,float *totreg,float *totovt,float *totgp,float *totfed,
                        float *totstt,float *totsst,float *totdef,float *totnp,int *empCount);//3.2
    do
    {

      printf("Enter employee's name: ");  // input section
      scanf("%s%s",r.firstname,r.lastname);
      printf("Enter hourly pay rate: ");
      scanf("%f",ADDR(r.payrate));
      printf("Enter deferred amount: ");
      scanf("%f",ADDR(r.defr));
      printf("Enter hours worked this pay period: ");
      scanf("%f",ADDR(r.hours));
          if (r.hours > 40)
          {
               reghours = 40;
               ovthours = r.hours - 40;
          }
          else {
               reghours = r.hours;
               ovthours = 0;
          }      
      r.gross = (reghours * r.payrate)+(ovthours * r.payrate * 1.5);
      CalculateTaxes(r.gross,r.defr,&ft,&st,&ssit);//Call 3.5 CalculateTaxes 

      r.net = r.gross - ft - st - ssit;
      printf(REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS1);
      printf(REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS2);
      printf(BARS); 
      printf(REPORTCOLUMN1,r.lastname,r.firstname,r.payrate,reghours,r.gross,ft,ssit,r.net); 
      printf(REPORTCOLUMN2,ovthours,st,r.defr);   
          ReportFile = fopen("report.txt", "a");
          fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMN1,r.lastname,r.firstname,r.payrate,reghours,r.gross,ft,ssit,r.net); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMN2,ovthours,st,r.defr); 
          fclose(ReportFile);

void AddDetailToAccumulators(int *empCount,float *totpr,float *totfed,float *totreg,float *totovt,
                         float *totgp,float *totstt,float *totsst,float *totnp,float *totdef,float *r.payrate);//3.7

      avgpr = totpr / empCount;
      avgfedt = totfed / empCount;
      avgreg = totreg / empCount;
      avgovt = totovt / empCount;
      avggp = totgp / empCount;
      avgstt = totstt / empCount;
      avgsst = totsst / empCount;
      avgnp = totnp / empCount;
      avgdef = totdef / empCount;

          fflush(stdin);
          printf(" Repeat (Y/N)? : ");
          scanf("%c",ADDR(answer)); 
    } while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
        printf("\n"); // print one line for spacing 
   printf("\nTotals %17.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",totpr,totreg,totgp,totfed,totsst,totnp); 
   printf("%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n",totovt,totstt,totdef); 
   printf("\nAverages %15.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",avgpr,avgreg,avggp,avgfedt,avgstt,avgnp); 
   printf("%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n",avgovt,avgsst,avgdef);
          ReportFile = fopen("report.txt", "a");
          fprintf(ReportFile,"\nTotals %17.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",totpr,totreg,totgp,totfed,totsst,totnp); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,"%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n",totovt,totstt,totdef); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,"\nAverages %15.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",avgpr,avgreg,avggp,avgfedt,avgsst,avgnp); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,"%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n",avgovt,avgstt,avgdef);
          fclose(ReportFile);   
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void PrintReportHeadings(FILE *ReportFile)//3.1
{    
 ReportFile = fopen("report.txt", "w");
 fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS1);
 fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS2);
 fprintf(ReportFile,BARS);
 fclose(ReportFile);
}
void InitializeAccumulators(float *totpr,float *totreg,float *totovt,float *totgp,float *totfed,
                        float *totstt,float *totsst,float *totdef,float *totnp,int *empCount)//3.2
{
 empCount = 0;  
 totpr = totreg = totovt = totgp = totfed = totstt = totdef = totsst = totnp = 0;
}
void AddDetailToAccumulators(int *empCount,float *totpr,float *totfed,float *totreg,float *totovt,
                         float *totgp,float *totstt,float *totsst,float *totnp,float *totdef,float *r.payrate)
{
 empCount = empCount + 1;
      totpr = totpr + payrate;
      totfed = totfed + ft;
        if (r.hours > 40)
          {
               reghours = 40;
               ovthours = r.hours - 40;
          }
          else {
               reghours = r.hours;
               ovthours = 0;
          }
      totreg = totreg + reghours;    
      totovt = totovt + ovthours;
      totgp = totgp + r.gross;
      totstt = totstt + st;
      totsst = totsst + ssit;
      totnp = totnp + r.net;
      totdef = totdef + r.defr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are pointer types, but then you use them as primitives.

That can't be good.

You also need to study up on pass by reference and pass by value InitializeAccumulators() just doesn't do what you assume it does.